# Spatial Distribution /Simulation/ Density Function

Tags: multithreading, r, performance, spatial, multicore

Just imagine you have rather large dataset of **2.000.000 points** randomly destributed over some polygonal space.
Density function has to be measured any time from randomly chosen sample of 4.000 points. This process has to be repeated 200 times. My code doesn't cover this problem very well. Any suggestion how to improve the code.

```
# coord is SpatialPoints Object 
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(map)
```

You can get the polygonial object from the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/65c3rke0gi4d8pb/LAKJWhwm-l

```
germG <- readShapePoly("vg250_gem.shp")
coord <- spsample(germG, 2e06, "random") # this command needs some minutes to be done. 

# R is the number of simulations
R <- 200
M <- matrix(NA,R, 256)
ptm=proc.time()
for(r in 1:R) {
  ix <- sample(1:2e06,size=4000)
  Dg <- spDists(coord[ix])
  Dg <- as.vector(Dg[Dg!=0])
  kg <- density(Dg,bw="nrd0",n=256)
  M[r,] <- kg$y
}
runningtime = proc.time()-ptm   
cat("total run time (sec) =",round(runningtime[3],1),"\n")
```

the upper code provides a total run time (sec) = 964.8 by using Core i3, 2.27Ghz, 4 processors and 4 Gb RAM.  How to speed up the performance of this for-loop simulation?
I'll be very thankful to all your comments, critics and suggestions.

Comment: Add more comments to your code always helps other people follow it better.  Also, what specifically is the slowest point?  What is your goal for performance (e.g. a specific amount of time)?

Comment: @camdixon I have added more information by editing the initial text. Thank you for advising.

Comment: So coords are the 2 million points  but you only start measuring time after the R (200) sample points are created and the M matrix is created.  I would measure time at the very start, see how long it takes to create the coordinates, then measure again to see how long it takes to sample.  Also, based on your code I have no idea where you set $y, can you clarify this for me with comments?

Comment: also with multiple cores it only takes advantage of them if it's multithreaded application.  Ensure that this is running with multiple threads being created if parts of it can run at the same time (e.g. If 200 samples of size 4,000 are created I see no reason why you couldn't have different threads handling 20-40 samples each).  Current processes operate much much better with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, just some observations:

1. If R= # iterations, and S= sample size per iteration (e.g., R=200 and S=4000), then your run time will be ~O(R × S<sup>2</sup>). So doubling runs and halving sample size will reduce run time by a factor of 2.
2. The default distance metric in `spDists(...)` is Euclidean. If this is what you want, then you are much better off using the `dist(..)` function - it is much more efficient (see code below). If you want geographic distance (e.g., Great Circle) you have to use `spDists(..., longlat=T)`.
3. `spDists(...)` calculates the full distance matrix, not just the lower diagonal. This means that all non-zero distances show up twice, which has an effect on your densities. This is why M1 and M2 in the code below are *not* equal.
4. For large S, profiling your code (using `Rprof`) shows that about 46% of the time is spent in `density(...)`, and another 38% is spent in `spDists(...)`. So this is one case where replacing the for loop with calls to apply, lapply etc. will not help much.
5. There are other functions for calculating a geographic distance matrix - assuming that's what you want, but none were faster than what you are already using. I tried `earth.dist(...)` in the `fossil` package, `distm(...)` from the `geosphere` package, and `rdist.earth(...)` in the `fields` package, but none of these improved run times.

Code:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
germG <- readShapePoly("vg250_gem.shp")
coord <- spsample(germG, 1e4, "random") # Just 10,000 points...
R <- 200

# dist(...) and spDists(..., longlat=F) give same result
zz <- coord[sample(1e4,size=200)]
d1 <- spDists(zz)
d2 <- dist(zz@coords)
max(abs(as.matrix(d1)-as.matrix(d2)))
# [1] 0
# but dist(...) is much faster
M1 <- matrix(NA,R, 256)
set.seed(1)
system.time({
  for(r in 1:R) {
    ix <- sample(1e4,size=200)    # S = 200; test case
    Dg <- spDists(coord[ix])      # using spDists(...)
    Dg <- as.vector(Dg[Dg!=0])
    kg <- density(Dg,bw="nrd0",n=256)
    M1[r,] <- kg$y
  }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   11.08    0.17   11.28 

M2 <- matrix(NA,R, 256)
set.seed(1)
system.time({
  for(r in 1:R) {
    ix <- sample(1e4,size=200)    # S = 200; test case
    Dg <- dist(coord[ix]@coords)  # using dist(...)
    Dg <- as.vector(Dg[Dg!=0])
    kg <- density(Dg,bw="nrd0",n=256)
    M2[r,] <- kg$y
  }
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.67    0.03    2.73
```

**Edit** In response to OP's request.
Below is the profiling code with size=200.

```
R=200
M <- matrix(NA,R, 256)
Rprof("profile")
set.seed(1)
system.time({
  for(r in 1:R) {
    ix <- sample(1e4,size=200)    # S = 200; test case
    Dg <- spDists(coord[ix])      # using spDists(...)
    Dg <- as.vector(Dg[Dg!=0])
    kg <- density(Dg,bw="nrd0",n=256)
    M[r,] <- kg$y
  }
})
Rprof(NULL)
head(summaryRprof("profile")$by.total,10)
#                   total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
# "system.time"          11.52    100.00      0.02     0.17
# "spDists"               7.08     61.46      0.02     0.17
# "matrix"                6.76     58.68      0.24     2.08
# "apply"                 6.58     57.12      0.26     2.26
# "FUN"                   5.88     51.04      0.22     1.91
# "spDistsN1"             5.66     49.13      3.36    29.17
# "density"               3.18     27.60      0.02     0.17
# "density.default"       3.16     27.43      0.06     0.52
# "bw.nrd0"               1.98     17.19      0.00     0.00
# "quantile"              1.76     15.28      0.02     0.17
```

As S gets bigger, calculating density begins to dominate because the results must be sorted. You can run this code with `ix <- sample(1e4,size=4000)` to see it.

Comment: The differencies in M1 and M2 are caused by bw="nrd0" (Silverman methode of choosing bandwidth), if you fix h <- 10000 and after bw =h, the M1 and M2 will be same. I think it was quite good help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please send me the profiling of my code (Rprof) to my email(and.stepanyan(at)gmail.com). I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work well. Another way to increase the computitional power was the idea of @camdixon to try spliting the processor cores. I have never done something like this, do you have already any experiences how it can be done? Now I'm working on this, if I'll find anything worth it, I'll also share with you.

Comment: See my edit for the profiling code. I had already deleted the profile - sorry.

Comment: @jlhoward Great work, I didn't know this particular language so I couldn't help that much.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it is marginally faster to define a blank matrix DG ahead of time.

Beyond that, you may want to consider a multicored application, granting sufficient RAM space.

Comment: You might know any methode which will made it possible to split the cores speeding up performance of codes like mine is.